# Dividing existing files into multiple files containing specific fields respectively

Tags: loops, cut

I have a tab separated `file_all` with 21 fields.

```
header    f1    f2    f3    f4 ...
name1     a     b     c     d  ...
...
```

I need 20 separate files such that file1 contains

```
header    f1    
name1     a     
...
```

and file2 contains

```
header    f2    
name1     b     
...
```

I can manually do this by

```
cut -f1,3 file_all > file1
```

and so on.
Is there an automated way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


for ((n=2; n<22; n++))
{
    cut -f 1,"$n" file_all > file${n}

}
```

This is the code I've used to resolve this.